# @ в Matlab коде

Tags: matlab

Это такой способ получения ссылки на функцию? 
Например, если написать вот так: `@isnumeric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это ссылка на функцию, которую можно передать как параметр другой функции. Например,

```
integral(@sin, 0, pi)
```

интегрирует синус от 0 до pi.

Этот символ также используется для анонимных функций, где определение и получение ссылки проходят одновременно:

```
f = @(x) 3*sin(x) 
f(pi/2)               %   возвращает 3
integral(f, 0, pi)    %   возвращает 6
```